# Trying to launch a file in an anonymous delegate tied to a toast event fails (C# Winrt)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a function that downloads an image, and when the download completes it triggers a toast notification.  When the user clicks the toast notification, I want to open the file using the default program.  But the launcher fails when it's inside of an anonymous delegate.

Here is the code that sets up the anonymous delegate

```
            var savefolder= await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("savefolder");
            Uri source;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(ImageUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out source))
            {
                return;
            }
            var destination = imageFileName;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destination))
            {
                return;
            }
            var destinationFile = await savefolder.CreateFileAsync(destination, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var data = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(source);
            var targetStream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            await targetStream.AsStreamForWrite().WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            await targetStream.FlushAsync();
            targetStream.Dispose();
            TypedEventHandler<ToastNotification, object> openPic =
                async delegate(ToastNotification toastSender, object toastArgs)
                {
                    var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(destinationFile);
                    var i = 0;
                };
            CommentProcessing.LoadToast("The image has been saved to your pictures library", openPic);
```

Here is the Toast function

```
    public static void LoadToast(string text, TypedEventHandler<ToastNotification, object> toastActivated = null)
    {
        var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
        var elements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        elements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(text));
        var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        if (toastActivated != null)
            toast.Activated += toastActivated;
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    }
```

Now, it works almost exactly as planned.  The delegate fires and calls the launcher.  But when it tries to launch, it fails.

I've been able to step through the code, and when the delegate fires, all the file information is still intact.

Any ideas?

Comment: it fails == exception thrown?  or just doesn't do anything?

Comment: the variable "success" is set to false. No exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a long shot, but you could try offloading the opening of the image to the dispatcher:

```
TypedEventHandler<ToastNotification, object> openPic =
    async delegate(ToastNotification toastSender, object toastArgs)
    {
        Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
            () => var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(destinationFile);
    };
```

Comment: Holy crap, that worked!  Thanks.  I just had to change the anonymous method in your example into an async method.